# One friend can't join server, others can

Tags: networking, router, dns, firewall

Basic Info:
Router : Netgear R6230
Port 25565 is forwarded.
I have administrator privileges for both the hosting computer and the router.

I've been hosting a minecraft server for my friends and everything was working fine. Out of the blue one day, one of my friends was unable to join whereas he could previously. Everyone else can still connect just fine. I had him try pinging my IP address and he gets a request timed out error. I had him do a traceroute and it seems like it reaches all the way to my town of residence before timing out. It is day two of him being unable to connect.

Stuff we've tried and has failed to work:

- Restarted both computers (first thing of course!)
- I figure this is most likely my firewall blocking him for some reason
  so I tried adding an inbound rule specifically for his IP address
  (for all ports).
- Tried adding an exclusion for his IP address in Malwarebytes (My only
  security software). I also tried just turning off Malwarebytes.
- Tried having my friend disable his anti-virus and tried having him
  change his DNS Servers to google's public ones and neither helped.

I would think there is some kind of firewall-like system going on in the router as well, but I could not find any options to allow connections from a specific address on my router page.

My limited knowledge in networking has run me out of ideas. If anyone can suggest something we can try I would be very thankful.

Comment: This could be an issue on your router (eg.connection tracking/firmware issue) Have you tried rebooting that?

Comment: Excellent Idea! I will try this later today once he gets online. Thank you!

Comment: Tried turning the router off for a bit, had my friend try connecting again after it rebooted and still nothing.

Comment: I wonder if its an ISP level block. What OS is the hosting computer? Can your other friends ping your IP?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10, friend is running Windows 7. Any way to find out if it's an ISP level block? Something I can test for?

Comment: Im a Linix person, so I dont know Windowsbtools, but I would run tcpdump on my server and router - filtered to look for traffic to/from the external IP your friend and adk them to connect to confirm if traffic is rraching my system.